# SignalR sends empty messages to some of the clients

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I have several websites which implements signalR.
All works well.

Now I added a new site. I can see from the client side (using dev tools) connecting to signalR (also getting success on connection).

Now I can see it connects using server sent events but all messages are empty.
I open another client (another web site which connects to the same signalR service) and I can see the message rates is much faster and of course with data.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Kind regards.

Comment: are you using autofac by any chance?

Comment: Cant remember...